# changing and image in a div but can't give it and javascript variable id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I thought this would be simple. I am changing an image in div but I can't seem to set the id of the image of the div.

```
    var my_html = "<img src=\"/img/lock.png\" id=\"" + json_obj.ITEM_VALUE_ID "+  \" />"
     $("#up-down-icons-"+id+"-"+level).html( my_html  );
```

I get

```
    <img id=" + json_obj.ITEM_VALUE_ID + " src="/img/lock.png">
```

json_obj.ITEM_VALUE_ITEM is defined. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?  I think I just need a second pair of eyes.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your javascript syntax, This is a good way :

```
var my_html = "<img src='/img/lock.png' id='" + json_obj.ITEM_VALUE_ID + "' />";
$("#up-down-icons-"+id+"-"+level).html(my_html);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be this

```
var my_html = "<img src=\"/img/lock.png\" id=\"" + json_obj.ITEM_VALUE_ID +  "\" />"
```

You just misplaced the position of the plus